# Product formula of two matrices in the Minkowski space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

The definition of the dot product of two vectors $x= <x_{1} ,x_{2},x_{3}>,\,\,\,  y =<y_{1} ,y_{2},y_{3}>$ in the [Minkowski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space) is : $<x,y>= - x_{1} y_{1} + x_{2} y_{2}+ x_{3} y_{3}$

If I have 2 matrices say $\left( 
\begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\ 
d_1 & e_1 & f_1 \\ 
g_1 & h_1 & i_1
\end{array}
\right)$ and $\left( 
\begin{array}{ccc}
a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\ 
d_2 & e_2 & f_2 \\ 
g_2 & h_2 & i_2
\end{array}
\right)$. What should be the formula for the product of these two matrices? Is it analogous to the definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication), with the dot product of two vectors defined as above?

Comment: Matrix multiplication is defined once and for all irrespectively of your inner product.  At your own peril you may want to define a new multiplication but I believe this has not been considered in the literature and so you will have to develop it's properties from scratch.